# How to show element or input after data is successfully verified? Codeigniter Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have successfully verify if the data is recorded and not. The problem is I cannot show the button or input if the data has been successfully verified.

Right now the problem that I have is even though the data is correct or incorrect, the button displays.

What I need is it to display for the correct data only.

Here is my View

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="studId" />
    <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Class Code:</h5>
                <small><li>Only teachers shall give you code</li></small><br>
                <input type="text" id="code" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Enter class code to join" name="code" required />
                <span id="code_result"></span>  

    </div>
    <hr>
                <button id="btnVerify" class="btn btn-success">Verify</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Join Class</button>
```

And its script

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').hide();

    //Verify
    $('#btnVerify').click(function(){
        var code = $('#code').val();  
           if(code != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>students/check_code_avalibility",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{code:code},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#code_result').html(data);  

                          if(code === true){
                            $('#btnSubmit').hide();
                          }else{
                            $('#btnSubmit').show();
                          }
                     }  
                });  
           }    
    });
});

</script>
```

In the controller

```
function check_code_avalibility()  
{  

          if(!$this->student_model->is_code_available($_POST["code"]))  
          {  
               echo '<label class="text-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Invalid Code</label>';  
          }  
          else  
          {  
               echo '<label class="text-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Code Available</label>';  
          }  

}
```

And in the Model

```
function is_code_available($code)  
{  
     $this->db->where('code', $code);  
     $query = $this->db->get("groups");  
     if($query->num_rows() > 0)  
     {  
          return true;  
     }  
     else  
     {  
          return false;  
     }  
}
```

Comment: change your codes to this  `if(code === true){
                            $('#btnSubmit').show();
                          }else{
                            $('#btnSubmit').hide();
                          }`. And your code in if statement should be result of data.

Comment: `code === true` this will always be `false` because your `code` variable is a string. You need to check for `data` instead